# How to compare current working tree file with last previous version (git or local history)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

(I think) I need a way to compare my current file with the modifications from previous commit (in this case, it might also be a the last saved version in local history).

## git history

When the file of interest is open I left click on the last commit in the timeline:

I thought that gives me the current file compared to the previous commit **and I thought I can make changes to the current file** in the diff view to get some changes back from the previous commit or so.

That is not the case. The diff editor that opens shows the diff of selected commit in the timeline with the previous one. Both editor panes are read-only:

[image: Diff with last commit]

(Maybe that is okay to show it this way, but if it is, how to compare the current file to the most recent commit?)

I know there are many extensions. I don't want to use a huge extension like gitlens to get this solved. I think vscode already has enough functionality built in that would make it possible to compare current version to last version.

## Saved file history

Left clicking the last saved version of the local history shows the most recent versions in a diff view **on both panes**. I thought it shows the current working tree file with the changes made in the last save (also: local file editable). It does not show any changes:

[image: Diff with last save in local history]

All this is not intuitive for me, but also not a direct issue or bug. Instead of creating an issue I followed the tip to ask here at Stackoverflow first as mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/15253f1528573fc8f84e956b21af4bad57f38c07/CONTRIBUTING.md#asking-questions). I hope the dev team would look into this and see how (some) users might interpret this UI/UX.

Answer (score 1):

## git history

**One way** for showing the **changes between git and current workspace** file it seems there are **editor decorations** that can be clicked and then show the diff as a kind of peek preview:

[image: Peek preview screenshot]

**another way** is to use the `Show changes` button in a file with modifications in comparison to git:

[image: Show changes button]

This function opens the last changes in comparison to the latest commit **and the local file shown is editable**.

[image: Opened changes]

## Saved file history

> Left clicking the last saved version of the local history shows the most recent versions in a diff view on both panes. I thought it shows the current working tree file with the changes made in the last save (also: local file editable). It does not show any changes:

**This shows** the changes between the last save of the file and **the unsaved changes** to the file. **The pane with the unsaved changes is editable**.

[Editor with unsaved changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsxjZ.png)

[Diff with unsaved changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j60y.png)